# Importing large contact file error message and failure --why?

Tags: wordpress, file, import, matching

I am trying to import a large csv contact file directly to Civicrm "Contact Import" page.  The file has about 60,000 lines of contact information, such as name, last name, middle initial, Street Address, Suplement Address 1, City, State, Zip Code, Phone, email.....etc.   When all matching fields is completed in the second step, the mapping creates the following Error:

```
                                 Temporarily Unavailable
```

We apologize for the inconvenience, but this page is currently unavailable. Please check back again later.

```
                                 504 Gateway Timeout
```

The backend service failed to respond within the expected amount of time.
If you are the website owner, please check status.inmotionhosting.com for outage details, or contact our support team if you require assistance.

We cannot disclose any information regarding this account if you are not its owner or authorized party. For the security and privacy of our customers, all account requests are verified prior to the disclosure of account information.

Please advice on how to solve this problem since we have enough bandwidth, memory and the time for upload is sufficient.  Thank You

matched all the fields correctly and the error message followed

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache (nginx if applicable), and php error logs which should tell you exactly what the error is beyond just a Timeout Error.

The [recommended PHP settings for CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php-configuration) are:

- memory_limit 256M
- max_execution_time 240
- max_input_time 120
- post_max_size and upload_max_filesize 50M

Check to see if your php.ini is set to at least those minimum settings and consider upping those to see if that allows you to complete the import.

Also, try a smaller import to ensure that the import function is working on the server.

Comment: Thank You.  All the settings have been increased greater than those numbers to allow less risk of error message.  I will try to find the error message in php now